# Are CITY and Nichijou set in the same universe?

Tags: nichijou, city

Recently, I've started reading *CITY*, the manga that Arawi Keiichi started working on after finishing *Nichijou*.

There are apparently some *Nichijou* cameos in *CITY*, such as this blue-haired mangaka named ["Naganohara Daisuke"](https://citymanga.wikia.com/wiki/Daisuke_Naganohara) who briefly appears in chapter 25, and also this [book cover](https://numahachi.tumblr.com/post/169861278609/ogi-confirmed) by someone named "Ogi Wataru", which briefly appears in chapter 59.

Does this mean *CITY* and *Nichijou* are set in the same universe? Or are these just easter eggs? Is there any other evidence, for example, word from the mangaka, or perhaps any additional cameos?